# Set on item click listener for items in a listview and go to a new activity

Tags: android

I have list view(data is retrieved from the database and put into the listview). What I want to do is make each item in the clickable and once clicked I want it to go to a new activity I have tried a `setOnItemClickListener` but it does not work

```
public class MomentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   ListView listView;
    TextView description;
    TextView location;
    TextView name;
    //ImageView image; used later when we want to display the image

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_moments:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this, MomentsActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_addmoment:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this, AddMomentActivity.class);
                    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moments);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        mList = this.findViewById(R.id.my_listview);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
        mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("textview_name", listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        manageListView();






        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
    }




    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editTitle, editDescription, editLocation;
    Button btnAddData;
    Button btnViewAll;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA; //Adapts/Handles the data for the listview
    ListView mList;
    Cursor mCsr;


    int[] item_layout_ids_for_list = new int[]{
            R.id.textview_name,
            R.id.textview_description,
            R.id.textview_location
    };

    String[] columns_to_list = new String[]{
            DatabaseHelper.COL_2,
            DatabaseHelper.COL_3,
            DatabaseHelper.COL_5
    };

    private void manageListView() {
        mCsr = myDb.getAllData();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            // Builds the Adapter for the List
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.mylistview_item, mCsr,
                    columns_to_list,
                    item_layout_ids_for_list,
                    0
            );
            mList.setAdapter(mSCA); // Ties the Adapter to the ListView
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr); // Refresh the List
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _It doesn't work_ ? Do you get an error, an exception ? Nothing's happening ? Did you try to add a Logcat log in your `onItemClick`, to be sure your click is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best approach to use to execute an action after the click in a list is to do it in your `getview()` method inside **listview** **adapter**

so in your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   .....
   .....

  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //use context in adapter constructor;
             Activity activity = (Activity) context 
             Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("textview_name", listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
             activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
});


return view ;
}
```

and don't forget to remove your `setOnItemClickListener` on `listview`